# I need recommendation for small server

Tags: server, web-server

I'm looking for a small server to prepare my business item and collect data(some blog articles).
I'm planning to run solution written by PHP or Python.
So, what I want to ask is which one is better, VM on the desktop I'm using(i7-930 with 16GB RAM) or an old laptop(i3 3217U with 4GB RAM)
Currently, I'm running IIS server with Windows 10 Pro on the old laptop.
But still I'm considering other options.
I tried Ubuntu Server on laptop, but I can't configure WLAN because it doesn't have Ethernet port on it and solutions on the Internet not worked.
On the other hand, only problem using VM on my desktop is I play various games on it.
So what should I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only for personal use then you don't really care about performance, a Raspberry Pi 3 would be enough (but beware filesystem errors).

Otherwise get something cheap in the cloud. Hosting websites, especially if you want it up and running almost all the time has so much hidden costs (Internet, UPS, electricity, labor) it turns out cloud solutions are the cheapest option.

Comment: Wow...I should consider Azure again. I tried Azure web app, but it was so difficult.

Comment: Might as well get the Pi 4 and spend an extra $20 on the 4gb ram version.

Comment: @cybernard I mention the Pi 3 on purpose to underline the low specs required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm seriously thinking about various options because MariaDB keep going off related to 'buffer size' problem so I'm using MySQL x64. I also considered RPi 4 4GB RAM version but some people said RPi(They didn't talk about which version of RPi) only can hold 5 simultaneous connections. I'm testing Azure web app on F1 grade infra, but it's slow. It's really difficult to choose.

Comment: @Sweetbarrow I keep forgetting it's Windows, it might have something to do with this. I once had a GitLab instance on a single vCPU host with 4 GB for a 10-people dev team. It perhaps depends too much on your application and I should've been more careful with my answer instead of assuming it's something like a website.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful anyway. After I read your answer, I tried Azure Web App B1 tier. But I'm still running my old laptop server because of speed. I'm still considering a server with cheap price, easy to set, and enough performace.